Filter json to keep sub-content that matches a given pattern anywhere in the key or value
Suppose I have a json file. I want to filter this file to only output content where a given pattern appears in anywhere in the full path or leaf node value. For example, suppose the json file has below content:
{
 "a": "foo",
 "b": "bar",
 "c": {
  "d": "foo",
  "e": "bar"
 },
 "aa": {
  "foo": [
   1,
   2,
   3
  ],
  "bar": {
   "foo": false
  }
 }
}

And the pattern is "foo". Then, the output should be as follows.
{
 "a": "foo",
 "c": {
  "d": "foo"
 },
 "aa": {
  "foo": [
   1,
   2,
   3
  ],
  "bar": {
   "foo": false
  }
 }
}

So, what should the jq command be?

what should be output for: {"k": [ "foo", "bar" ] } ?

If the following does not match your expectations entirely, then hopefully you'll be able to tweak it so that it does:
def prune(cond):
  def prune_object: 
    . as $in 
    | reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k ({};   # preserve ordering
        if ($k|cond) then .[$k] = $in[$k]
        else [$in[$k] | prune(cond)] as $x
        | if $x == [] then .
          else .[$k] = $x[0]
          end
        end )
    | select(. != {});
  if type == "object" then prune_object
  elif type == "array" 
  then map(prune(cond))
  | select(. != [])
  elif type == "string" then select(cond)
  else empty
  end;

prune(test"foo"))

This formulation has the advantage that you can easily specify similar alternatives, e.g.
prune(. == "foo")
or
prune( startswith("foo") )
or
prune( test("foo"; "i") )

the "delete-all" test I added to my answer (bascially {"a":[{"b":1}]}) seems to confuse your code. I think the if $x test wants to be after the output of the if type test but I don't know enough to suggest a fix

perhaps simplify if $x ... then to if $x==[] then and change empty end to empty end | select(.!=[] and .!={}) ?

Because I don't know how to write proper jq code:
jq --stream -c < file.json |
grep -e 'foo' -e ']]$' |
jq -n 'fromstream(inputs)'

or:
jq --stream -n < file.json '
    fromstream(
        inputs | select(
            (length == 1)
            or any(
                (.[0][], .[1]) | strings;
                test("foo")
            )
        )
    )
'


input:
{
 "a": "foo",
 "b": "bar",
 "c": {
  "d": "foo",
  "e": "bar"
 },
 "aa": {
  "foo": [
   1,
   2,
   3
  ],
  "bar": {
   "foo": false
  },
  "delete-this": {
   "not": "wanted"
  }
 },
 "delete-all": {
   "x": {
     "a": {
       "b": {
         "c": 1
       }
     }
   },
   "y": {
      "a": [
        {
          "b": [
            1
          ]
        }
      ]
   }
 },
 "keep-part": [
  "foo",
  "bar"
 ]
}

output:
{
  "a": "foo",
  "c": {
    "d": "foo"
  },
  "aa": {
    "foo": [
      1,
      2,
      3
    ],
    "bar": {
      "foo": false
    }
  },
  "keep-part": [
    "foo"
  ]
}


The last answer is very good except that it would be much better to replace the RHS of the or with: any(.[0][], .[1] | strings;  test("foo"))

@peak having seen oguz' answer, I was literally just reading up on any operator :-)

Here is a way:
def f:
  def g:
    def h: type == "string" and test("foo") | not;
    del(getpath(
      paths(scalars, select(IN([], {}))) | select(all(h))
    ) | select(h));
  . as $in | g | if . != $in then f end;
f

Online demo
